# How to forbid 2 users to edit the same data in a web application using MySQL (with CodeIgniter if possible)

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, transactions, locking, mariadb

I use CodeIgniter 3 and MariaDB 5.0 on my dev environment (but MySQL 5.6 in the prod environment).

I created a web app, and implemented a validation chain to accept the user requests.

For example:

```
User A asked for something
The manager validate
The deputy validate
The commission validate
The accounting department validate
The request is accepted
```

Those validations are registered in the database, in several tables.

I uses the SQL transaction to update/insert the data correctly with
CodeIgniter's functions and CRUD models, example:

```
$this->db->trans_start();
$this->my_model->create($data);
$another_data = $this->second_model->read($second_data);
$this->another_model->create($another_data);
$this->db->trans_complete();
```

But now, I have to implement a new rule for the General Manager. He has the capacity to validate anytime, and this validation breaks the validation chain because it count as everyone had validated.

This case could be an example:

```
User A asked for something
The manager validate
The general manager validate
The request is accepted
```

I'm not sure how to implement this, because I realised that 2 users (the general manager and the deputy for example) could consult the same request, one refuses, the other validate, and the data are not consistent anymore.

Is the transaction good enough ? Like:

```
// User A asked for something
// The manager validate
// The deputy consult the request
// The manager consult the request
// The deputy validate:

    $this->db->trans_start();

    // check if already validated by the general manager
    if ($this->model->read($data)) {
        $this->db->trans_complete();
        // redirection to a warning page
    }
    else {
        $this->my_model->create($my_data);
    }
    $this->db->trans_complete();

    if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE)
        // redirection to another warning page

// The general manager wants to refuse at the same time but the deputy's transaction started first, so he's redirected to a warning page

    $this->db->trans_start();

    // check if already validated by anyone
    if ($this->model->read($data)) {
        $this->db->trans_complete();
        // redirection to a warning page
    }
    else {
        $this->my_model->create($my_data);
    }
    $this->db->trans_complete();

    if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE)
        // redirection to another warning page

// The validation chain continues after the deputy's validation
```

I thought about the LOCK TABLE to forbid a user to reach the validation page while someone else is consulting the same request. But `TRANSACTION` and `LOCK TABLE` are hard to implement because it can trigger implicit commits, and I'm not used enough to do this right.

I read about `START TRANSACTION READ WRITE` that could be a better solution, but I didn't understood the all thing, and I'm not sure how to implement this correctly.

Could anyone help me to implement the good strategy, and if possible the way to use these SQL functions if needed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I used the `FOR UPDATE` just after my query, here it is:

```
// the query for my results
private model_function_for_query() {
    $this->db->select('my_select');
    $this->db->from('my_table');
    $this->db->where('my_where_clause');

    return $this->db->get_compiled_select();
}

// the function to apply the FOR UPDATE on the query
public model_function() {
    $query = $this->model_function_for_query();
    $result = $this->db->query($query.' FOR UPDATE');

    return $result->row();
}
```

And in my controller:

```
// start the transaction
$this->db->trans_start();

// do the query, locking tables
$data = $this->my_model->model_function();

// check if the data has not changed
...

// if not, do the data treatment, else redirect to the warning page
...

// close the transaction
$this->db->trans_complete();

// check if the transaction failed, and do the stuff
if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE)
    ...
else
    ...
```